# server not returning json instead html code in android saying page not found, however in browser it works

Tags: php, android, json

my code was working perfectly. Suddenly today in android code doesn't return json instead html code which has page not found content. However, if i browse that in a browser it is displaying json string perfectly.

My code in android:

```
try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null ) {
            //String check="\"S.No.\":\"\"" ;

                //String check=line.substring(4, 8);

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();         
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
      }
```

My code in php (www.dreamsint.com.np/nepse/index.json.php)

```
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("dreamsin_nepse",$conn) or die("could not select database");

$var = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($query,$conn);

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json_output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_output);

 mysql_close();
?>
```

Logcat output is :

```
 09-28 14:15:51.293: W/System.err(1633): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

While executing in android the string has these output

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification"     content="3xrrXSQdpSrRByvNOrx7q9m9qwWegGJPRfw6Iv8vdgI" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>
            Page Not Found |        </title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="http://www.dreamsint.com.np/xmlrpc.php" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.dreamsint.com.np/wp-content/themes/cloriato-lite/style.css" />
```

Comment: Your website probably blocks out requests from "not browsers" - e.g. java applications. Try playing with the headers of your URLConnection - you can use Developer's console in Chrome to see exactly what a real browser request sends to a website.

Comment: The url you've specified is not working for me from the browser. Maybe you're getting it from the cache.

Comment: my public_html folder was renamed to public_html.bak yesterday. I renamed back to public_html. is that a reason? i can browse www.dreamsint.com.np/nepse/index.json.php from all of my browser